# SQL trigger with SUM()

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

This is the table "Cars":
Cars(carId,color,price);

```
carId------color-------price
125         red        20000
101         blue       10000
104         black      30000
125         orange     15000
-and so on
```

I want to create a trigger, which will verify before insertion, if the sum of price is greater than
30000. And here is my code.

So I create a view(for not updating the same table with trigger)

```
CREATE VIEW VCars AS 
SELECT * FROM Cars 
WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

/

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CarSum
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Cars FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
     v_sum VCars.price%TYPE; 
BEGIN
     SELECT SUM(price)
     INTO v_sum 
     FROM VCars
     WHERE :NEW.carId=VCars.carId;
    if v_sum + :NEW.price >30000 then
        raise_application_error(-20000,'Stop this');
    end if;
    
END;
```

/

```
INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(125,"red",10000);
```

And the trigger is compiled, but it's not acting.Maybe de SUM function is not correctly used?

Comment: i think you have to use AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE trigger based on your data

Comment: Take away condition WHERE :NEW.carId=VCars.carId, because you select by carId not inserted row yet.

Comment: @SergeyAfinogenov but if I delete Where ,it will sum all prices

Comment: What does " if the sum of price is greater than 30000" mean? Which prices are to be added up?

Comment: Example for carId=125    20000+15000 +10000(the new one) > 30000

Comment: @readJohn in this case it works. I can't see any mistake

Comment: You're going to get a mutating table error on this. You can't select from the table you are inserting into in a row-level trigger.